# Find lowest common ancestor of tree like object (not binary tree) using recursion js

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I need some help with finding Lca of two nodes in the tree. So can anybody explain how to use recursion to traverse to some point and get result back. I saw many examples but no one of them can realy help me. This sort of problem is really new to me, I'm never used recursion for traverse the tree structures. Apreciate any help!

This is how my tree looks like, and this is one of many examples because it's randomly generated, and also I can't use any loops or forEach, array methods are allow only.

```
const tree = {
children: [ 
    { 
        children: [
            { 
                children: [],
                values: [15.667786122807836]
            }
        ],
        values: [35.77483035532576, 1.056418140526505]
    },
    {
        children: [
            {
                children: [
                    {
                        children: [],
                        values: [67.83058067285563]
                    }
                ],
                values: [98.89823527559626]
            }
        ],
        values: [51.49890385802418, 41.85766285823911]
    },
],
values: [6.852857017193847, 28.110428400306265, 51.385186145220494]};
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```js
const min = graph => {
  return Math.min(...graph.values, ...graph.children.map(graphNode => min(graphNode)));
};

const max = graph => {
  return Math.max(...graph.values, ...graph.children.map(graphNode => max(graphNode)));  
};
  
const distance = graph => {
  if (!graph.children.length && !graph.values.length) return; 
     const minValue = min(graph);
     const maxValue = max(graph);
     const findPath = (graph, key1, key2) => {
  
  if (graph.values.includes(key1) || graph.values.includes(key2)) {
     return graph.values;
 };
   
const arr = [graph.values].concat(graph.children.map(graphNode => {
  return findPath(graphNode, key1, key2);
}));
    
  return arr;
};
  
  const Lca = findPath(graph, minValue, maxValue);
  return Lca;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an overview of what your general algorithm is? Your problem statement says you get 2 nodes and need to return the lowest common ancestor, but your code seems to do something else.

Comment: So first of all I'm trying to find path from root node to each node with min and max values, if some of values was find, I'm return nodes back. Actually I don't know what to do next. I'm trying to use explanation what provided here:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-distance-between-two-given-nodes-in-an-n-ary-tree/

Comment: But without classes, like in the link above. Also my functions must be pure

Comment: and the most difficult part for me is than my root node has for example 3 childs how can I return only path from root to the node with min or max value

Comment: Why are you trying to find the nodes with min/max values? Aren't you given 2 nodes and you want to find their LCA? Why do you care about root to min/max node path? you LCA can be any node including root. I'm not sure you know what the lowest common ancestor of 2 nodes is.

Comment: Ok, may be I don't understand the problem. So if not lca than how to find distance between nodes with min and max values?

Comment: I know that lca can be any node including root but my whole task sounds like: Find the distance between two nodes with min and max values. If min and max in the same node return 0, if one value in the parent and second in the child return 1, if in the different childs return 2

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Then you are on the right track, the distance between 2 nodes in a tree is the sum of their distances to their LCA. But I couldn't see that clearly from the problem statement and code. Maybe I missed it :D

Comment: *"can't use any loops or forEach, array methods are allow only"*: `forEach` *is* an array method, and you are using `map` which is just as much a loop as `forEach` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `findPath` function returns `graph.values` as the base case, which is not going to help to build a path. Instead the indexes of the `children.map` iteration should be collected as the path.

And then when you have both the path to the minimum and the path to the maximum, you should ignore the prefix they have in common and count the remaining parts which represent the edges on the path between the two extreme nodes.

Here is a possible implementation:

```js
// the selector argument is a function that here will be either Math.min or Math.max:
function findPath(tree, selector) {
    const bestOf = (a, b) => selector(a[0], b[0]) === a[0] ? a : b;  
    const recur = (node, path) =>
        node.children.reduce((acc, child, i) => 
            bestOf(acc, recur(child, path.concat(i))),
        [selector(...node.values), path]);
    return recur(tree, [])[1];
}

function distanceMinMax(tree) {
    const min = findPath(tree, Math.min),
          max = findPath(tree, Math.max),
          common = min.findIndex((child, depth) => max[depth] != child);
    return min.length + max.length - (common < 0 ? min.length : common) * 2;
}

// Demo tree: the minimum is 1 and maximum is 10. Distance is 3.
const tree = {
    children: [{ 
        children: [{ 
            children: [],
            values: [3]
        }],
        values: [5, 1]
    }, {
        children: [{
            children: [{
                children: [],
                values: [9]
            }],
            values: [10]
        }],
        values: [8, 6]
    }],
    values: [2, 4, 7]
};

console.log(distanceMinMax(tree)); // 3
```

### Remarks

You wrote that you ... *"can't use any loops or `forEach`, array methods are allowed only."*

This is really a contradiction because:

- `.forEach()` *is* an array method;
- your code uses `.map()` which is quite similar to `.forEach()`;
- both `.map()` and `.includes()` represent a loop;
- It is quite natural to use loops when your data structure has `children` arrays, as any solution will have to visit each entry of such an array.

Comment: Regarding your remarks: This makes sense as a homework problem restriction, especially for a lesson teaching recursion. And I disagree with the idea that `map` and `forEach` are particularly close.  `map` has clear semantics.  `forEach` does not.  Also, both `map` and `includes` make sense extended to non array-like structures; so while they can be *implemented* for arrays using loops, they do not *represent* loops.

Comment: Mr. thank you very much). And thank you everybody who was trying to help. And of course I know that I can use forEach but I can't because of restrictions